# Postgresql constraint on 2 columns, so "col_a" cannot share any values of "col_b"

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, create-table, unique-constraint

I am building a database that has system barcodes, as well as the option for custom barcodes. I have a unique constraint on `custom_barcode` and `system_barcode`.

What I would like to do is have it so if `custom_barcode` has a value of “123”, no other row can have `custom_barcode` OR `system_barcode` with a value of “123". I am *not* trying to make a 2-column unique constraint where if `custom_barcode` is "123" and `system_barcode` is "456", that combination cannot exist again. Is it possible to achieve this? I'm wondering if this needs to be achieved with a trigger.

Answer (score 6):

If I follow you correctly, you can do this with a check constraint and an array-based exclusion constraint:

```
create table mytable (
    id serial primary key,
    custom_barcode int,
    system_barcode int,
    check (custom_barcode <> system_barcode),
    exclude using gist((array[custom_barcode, system_barcode]) with &&)
);
```

The check constraint ensures that the same value cannot be assign to both columns on the same row.

The exclusion constraint builds an array containing the two codes, and ensures that there is no other row whose array overlaps the current row.

Here is **[a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=01416f257ea02c6c750fcde16c938155)**:

```
insert into mytable (custom_barcode, system_barcode) values (1, 1);
-- ERROR:  new row for relation "mytable" violates check constraint "mytable_check"

insert into mytable (custom_barcode, system_barcode) values (2, 3);
-- ok

insert into mytable (custom_barcode, system_barcode) values (4, 2);
-- ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "mytable_array_excl"
-- DETAIL:  Key ((ARRAY[custom_barcode, system_barcode]))=({4,2}) conflicts with existing key ((ARRAY[custom_barcode, system_barcode]))=({2,3}).
```

Comment: what if I want to add third column to scope the combination based on that third column?, 

lets say year so in year 2023 I could input (2,3) and when I input (4,2) its failed because 2 is already inputted, but next year in 2024 I could add (4,2)